# Inserir dados no banco com foreach

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli, foreach

Tenho um array que recebe os dados de uma sessão e estou tentando inserir no banco usando foreach mas nada acontece. O que pode estar errado?

**Segue um exemplo do array:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_produto"]=>
    int(1)
    ["quantidade"]=>
    int(1)
    ["preco"]=>
    string(5) "10,00"
    ["total"]=>
    string(5) "10,00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_produto"]=>
    int(2)
    ["quantidade"]=>
    int(2)
    ["preco"]=>
    string(5) "45,50"
    ["total"]=>
    string(5) "91,00"
  }
}
```

**Segue um exemplo do meu código:**

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}

foreach($_SESSION['dados'] as $produto){
    require("conexao.php");
    mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tb_pedido (
    id,id_produto,
    id_usuario,
    id_categoria,
    quantidade,
    preco,
    total,
    data_cadastro,
    status) 
    VALUES (
    NULL,
    '".$produto['id_produto']."', 
    '0.0', '0.0', 
    '".$produto['quantidade']."', 
    '".$produto['preco']."', 
    '".$produto['total']."', 
    NOW(), 
    '0')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**Como meu banco está:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não posso comentar ainda, então vou responder, vejo que:

1 - ID é auto increment, não passe na query, retire o id, e o valor;
2 - Está passando float com virgula, deve ser ponto.

Acredito que seja um começo, pra solução

Comment: Era exatamente a questão 2. O FLOAT . Obrigado. Às vezes não nos atentamos à coisas pequenas hehe.

Comment: Acontece muito! As vezes perdemos horas e termina com um "Era só isso?!" não se irrita ou alivia.. hehe